# How to Keep Broadcast Receiver registered even if App is closed?

Tags: android

Please help me out, I want to keep my Broadcast Receiver always registered for receiving Broadcast.
I made it exported and enabled true in manifest also registered it in MainActivity but still after App is closed, it does not respond. The main issue is keeping registered.
I am Working on Android 8.

Comment: Use Service for the functionality to work, and relate your BR to that service.

Comment: Sir, I tried that but When App gets Closed Service also gets dismissed, so can you please guide on How to keep the service running all-time in the background.

Comment: Make sure you start a service as a foreground Service , In my opinion, JobIntentService is the modern way of using the background service to get our task done. The IntentService does not work well in our Oreo devices.I would use the JobIntentService in conjunction with AlarmManager to schedule low priority tasks like refreshing the widget's data periodically.

Comment: I tried JobIntentService it is also getting terminated when App is swiped from recent Apps, foreground Service is not Good, because it shows a Notification all the time.